# Rust lifetime confusion

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm currently teaching myself Rust and am practicing by implementing Tic-Tac-Toe.

I have a Board struct (`Cell` and `GameState` are straightforward enums, `SIZE` is `3 usize`):

```
struct Board {
    state : GameState,
    cells : [[Cell; SIZE]; SIZE],
}
```

and I'm trying to implement a `mark` method:

```
impl Board {
    fn mark(&mut self, pos: &Position, player: Player) {
        // various checks omitted
        // mark cell for player
        self.cells[pos.row][pos.col] = Cell::Filled(player);
        // check whether player has won either via a full row or column (diagonals omitted):
        if (0..SIZE).map(|i| &self.cells[pos.row][i]).all(|c| *c == Cell::Filled(player)) ||
           (0..SIZE).map(|i| &self.cells[i][pos.col]).all(|c| *c == Cell::Filled(player)) {
            self.state = GameState::Winner(player);
    }
}
```

so far so good... but there's the ugly code repetition.

so my next step was introducing a closure and replacing the repetition in the if with it:

```
let all_in_line = |cell_access| (0..SIZE).map(cell_access).all(|c : &Cell| *c == Cell::Filled(player));

if all_in_line(|i : usize| &self.cells[pos.row][i]) ||
   all_in_line(|i : usize| &self.cells[i][pos.col]) {
```

that does not work though because it would require for `all_in_line` to be generic (since the two closures that I pass to it have a different, anonymous type), so my next step was to do something akin to type erasure:

```
fn mark(&mut self, pos: &Position, player: Player) {
    let all_in_line = |cell_access : Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> &Cell>| (0..SIZE).map(cell_access).all(|c : &Cell| *c == Cell::Filled(player));
    if all_in_line(Box::new(|i : usize| &self.cells[pos.row][i])) ||
       all_in_line(Box::new(|i : usize| &self.cells[i][pos.col])) {
        self.state = GameState::Winner(player);
    }
```

But now the rust compiler complains about the lack of a lifetime parameter for the returned reference in the type specifier of `cell_access`:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
let all_in_line = |cell_access : Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> &Cell>| (0..SIZE).map(cell_access).all(|c : &Cell| *c == Cell::Filled(player));
                                                      ^ expected named lifetime parameter
```

I've tried modifying `mark` to `fn mark<'a>(&'a mut self, /*...*/)` and updating `cell_access`'s type accordingly: `Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> &'a Cell>` but this fails:

```
error[E0597]: `self` does not live long enough
fn mark<'a>(&'a mut self, pos: &Position, player: Player) {
        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
    if all_in_line(Box::new(|i : usize| &self.cells[pos.row][i]))
                           ----------- -^^^^------------------
                           |           ||
                           |           |borrowed value does not live long enough
                           |           returning this value requires that `self` is borrowed for `'a`
                           value captured here
...
}
- `self` dropped here while still borrowed
```

At this point, I've run out of ideas what's wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But now the rust compiler complains about the lack of a lifetime parameter for the returned reference in the type specifier of cell_access:

The problem here, as I understand it, is that in order to be able to write the code in this shape, the `cell_access` function's signature needs to refer to the lifetime *for which it is valid*, and this is impossible because that lifetime doesn't have a name — it's a *local reborrow of* `self` that's implicit in the closure creation. Your attempt with `&'a mut self` doesn't work because it doesn't capture the fact that the closure's `self` is a reborrow of the function's `self` and accordingly does not need to live *exactly the same lifetime*, since mutable borrows' lifetimes are invariant rather than covariant; they can't be arbitrarily taken as *shorter* (because that would break the exclusiveness of mutable references).

That last point gives me an idea for how to fix this: move the `all_in_line` code into a function which takes `self` by *immutable* reference. This compiles:

```rust
impl Board {
    fn mark<'a>(&'a mut self, pos: &Position, player: Player) {
        if self.all_in_line_either_direction(pos, player)
        {
            // self.state = GameState::Winner(player);
        }
    }
    
    fn all_in_line_either_direction<'a>(&'a self, pos: &Position, player: Player) -> bool {
        let all_in_line = |cell_access: Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> &'a Cell>| {
            (0..SIZE)
                .map(cell_access)
                .all(|c: &Cell| *c == Cell::Filled(player))
        };
        all_in_line(Box::new(|i: usize| &self.cells[pos.row][i]))
            || all_in_line(Box::new(|i: usize| &self.cells[i][pos.col]))
    }
}
```

---

However, while the above does work, I think the best option here is to, instead of trying to make `all_in_line` a closure, make it a separate function (which can be generic), and avoid using a `Box<dyn Fn>` at all.

In this position, we can write out the lifetime we actually need — the function's lifetime generic `<'a>` implies that the lifetime `'a` lasts *as long as `all_in_line` needs it* (a lifetime parameter can't end in the middle of the function call), whereas the closure taking a boxed function trait doesn't have *its own* generic scope.

```rust
fn all_in_line<'a, F>(player: Player, cell_access: F) -> bool
where
    F: Fn(usize) -> &'a Cell
{
    (0..SIZE).map(cell_access).all(|c| *c == Cell::Filled(player))
}
```

Then you have to pass `player` to each call, but there's none of the other complications.

If you like, you can even write the definition of `all_in_line` inside the `mark` function so it doesn't exist outside. Whether that's more readable code is up to your decision.

---

I added some pieces to be able to check that the code compiled; hopefully this all matches what you're actually doing:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct Player;

struct Position {
    row: usize,
    col: usize,
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Cell {
    Filled(Player),
}

const SIZE: usize = 10;

struct Board {
    // state: GameState,
    cells: [[Cell; SIZE]; SIZE],
}

impl Board {
    fn mark(&mut self, pos: &Position, player: Player) {
        self.cells[pos.row][pos.col] = Cell::Filled(player);
        if all_in_line(player, |i: usize| &self.cells[pos.row][i])
            || all_in_line(player, |i: usize| &self.cells[i][pos.col])
        {
            // self.state = GameState::Winner(player);
        }
    }
}

fn all_in_line<'a, F>(player: Player, cell_access: F) -> bool
where
    F: Fn(usize) -> &'a Cell,
{
    (0..SIZE)
        .map(cell_access)
        .all(|c| *c == Cell::Filled(player))
}
```

Comment: Note that to avoid polluting the global namespace, the `all_in_line` function can be defined inside `mark` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5d6ab65f87a54c7be22c2723c088369e)).

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a reasonable way to fix it. I'd still love to understand what exactly the problem with my code is though (and why your explicit function doesn't suffer from the same lifetime issues that my code does...)

Comment: @AndreasMorhammer I've added some more thoughts. I'm not quite good enough about thinking about this to give a total picture of "This can't work because … and if we tried to make the language different so it does then this other thing would break … " but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's very helpful!